# What does "pick a lemon" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I am struggling to figure out what the meaning of "lemon" or "pick a lemon" is in the following quote from P.G. Wodehouse:

> ...with each new book of mine I have, as I say, the feeling that this time I have picked a lemon in the garden of literature. A good thing, really, I suppose. Keeps one up on one's toes and makes one rewrite every sentence ten times. Or in many cases twenty times.

Comment: It's an extension (_pick a_ lemon [...]) of a secondary usage of the word 'lemon'. You can find this sense in a dictionary, today.

Comment: Some interesting comments [here](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/7/messages/1209.html)